# Add TextViews programmatically

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have an empty `LinearLayout`, and I need to add a dynamic number of `TextView`s to it. However when I use the code below, only the first `TextView` is shown:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] listofnumbers = new String[1000];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i )  {
        listofnumbers[i] = "null";
    }

    Context context = getBaseContext();

    String text = null;

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
    LinearLayout lv = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, dip(48));

    boolean v = true;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        String numberString = (cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address") ) ).replace(" ", "");

        int i = 0;
        boolean numberNotPresent = true;
        for (  ; listofnumbers[i] != "null" ; ++i ) {
            if ( numberString.equals(listofnumbers[i])  )   {
                numberNotPresent = false;
            }
        }
        if ( numberNotPresent == true ) {
            text = (CharSequence) "From: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")) + ": " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            listofnumbers[i] = numberString;
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(text);
            tv.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
            lv.addView( tv );
        }
    }
    setContentView(lv);
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: are you sure the condition `if ( numberNotPresent == true )` is being met? maybe add some logging and see if you're actually getting into that code and trying to add another TextView

Comment: Remove the condition for once and check again, if you get the TextView this time, means there's a problem in your condition. And I'd go with @dldnh about logging too.

Comment: set the params for thr linear layout

Comment: The conditions were being met. I had forgotten to set the LinearLayout orientation, as @bytebiscuit had suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change these two lines:

```
LinearLayout lv = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, dip(48));
```

with these:

```
LinearLayout lv = new LinearLayout(context);
        lv.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

basically you need to set the orientation for the lv LinearLayout to vertical as the default one is horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but may be for each textView you set fill_parent param? The 1st textView shows on all your layout.